# Почему неправильно отображаются ссылки на пользователей телеграм бота? TelegramBot,Nodejs,telegraf

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, telegraf

В моем телеграм боте есть админ команда, которая отображает юзернеймы пользователей. Каждый юзернейм кликабельный, и отправляет на профиль пользователя.
Для отображение кликабельного юзернейма использую строку:

```
<a href="tg://user?id=${user_.id}">${user_.username}</a>
```

Но вот незадача, для 2 из 6 пользователей ссылка не работает и выводится просто жирный юзернейм. Юзернеймы у пользователей открыты, айдишники сохранены правильно, не понимаю в чем проблема

Comment: Сразу уточню. Я знаю, как можно сделать по-другому. Но мне интересно, почему именно данный способ работает не всегда